# subprocess.Popen crashes when run in background

Tags: python, background, ffmpeg, subprocess, popen

In a program I'm working with right now, I try to check for the version of FFMPEG that is installed on the users machine. This works perfectly fine by using subprocess.Popen when run in the foreground OR when run in a detached screen.

However, when you run it in the background without screen (e.g. COMMAND &> /dev/null &) this process crashes the program. (see below) I've seen some people having similar issues on the web, but I still can't seem to fix this...

I've Any ideas?

```
version_ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg","-version"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=None)

f_out = version_ffmpeg.communicate()
(then...)
if f_out --> 3rd word contains --> etc.
```

Comment: what is the stderr for this execution

Comment: If it doesn't crash, its empty. If it crashes, it crashes, so i don't know.

Comment: I tried this example, I can see the output in stderr, sorry I dont know the reason please try

Comment: your question is unclear. What is `COMMAND`? Is it your parent Python script? If it is then what is the program? (do you run your Python script inside some other program?) What crashes? (ffmpeg, python, something else). What do you  mean by "crashes"? Use `output = check_output(['ffmpeg', '-version'], stderr=STDOUT)` and replace `/dev/null` with `/tmp/program.log`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. So what i'm doing is as follows:

1] I run a python simulation from command line 
2] In this python simulation, there is a call to check the installed
   version of FFMPEG (see above)
3] This works fine, UNLESS I background the command that start the python-simulation by using the following syntax on the command-line: 
python simulation.py --options &> /dev/null &